# Will I get a refund for my insurance renewal?

Tags: united-states, insurance, car-insurance, florida, chargeback

I Switched insurance from company A to company B. Insurance A had already charged the renewal amount December 9th even though I’m not due to renew until December 22nd (since that’s when my coverage ends). I called insurance A to ask if I would get refunded the renewal amount since I requested to cancel?

They said I had to wait 10days for the policy to cancel and then they would inform me if I was entitled to a refund. They also said they have to charge 10% of the insurance premium as a cancellation fee (I’m in Florida). I asked what premium they would charge the 10% on, the current premium or the one that would be effective once renewed on December 22nd? They said they were not sure and I had to call back after the policy is officially canceled (10 days) to ask about the 10% fee and the renewal refund, if any. And that the 10% would most likely be charged from the new premium (which is about 800$ more than the current premium I’m trying to cancel). How does this make sense??

I asked to speak to someone who could answer my refund questions but they kept telling me the same thing, I have to wait for the policy to cancel so that the finance/accounting department decided on the refund amount & 10% fee.

Is the normal? Should I seek legal advice? Or can I process a chargeback through my credit card company if they don’t refund me the renewal amount?

Comment: In Florida I'm not sure if they have regulations or oversight, but if they do - talk to the government agency responsible for insurance regulations. If not then... SOL?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the agent you spoke to may have been confused about your "cancellation" request. Partial refunds apply when you are cancelling mid-term, and might incur a fee as mentioned. It sounds like the agent thought you wanted an *immediate* cancellation with 10-12 days still remaining on your current policy. The pro-rated value of those few days wouldn't be very much, but it's not nothing.

Instead, what it sounds like you need is to simply *not renew* with company A. In this case your current policy would remain in effect until 22-Dec, no refund would be needed as you would need the policy to remain active all the way up until your next policy with company B takes effect. The premium that company A already charged would be fully refundable with no fee, as you haven't received anything (yet) for what was paid.